# Ускорить slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

Есть такая проблема: при загрузке страницы, блоки [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) отображаются друг под другом и только после полной загрузки выстраиваются как положено.

Занимает все не более секунды, но **вопрос:** как устранить данную проблему?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  

$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: false,
});

});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**P.S:** Задавать фиксированную высоту слайдеру и `overflow: hidden` (чтобы скрыть косяк) не вариант.

Comment: Скрыть все слайды кроме первого через css, а после загрузки страницы отобразить

Comment: @РашенБеар, Вы пробовали так делать?)

Comment: @ Elena нет, я смирился с таким поведением)

Comment: lazy load это вариант ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, тоже вряд ли, слик неадекватно воспринимает display block\none (если  сам внутри такого блока или если внутри него блоки так меняют св-во)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function init(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true
  })
};
//Запуск с задержкой
setTimeout(init,3000);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 15px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.slide{
  padding:10px;
}

/*Пока слайдер не инициализировался*/
.slider:not(.slick-initialized){
  display:flex;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.slide:not(.slick-slide){
  width:50%;/*Зависит от начального количества слайдов*/
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.aguanaboca.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aaasd.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.aguanaboca.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aaasd.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.aguanaboca.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aaasd.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.aguanaboca.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aaasd.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо пояснить ваше решение...

Comment: Пока (если) слайдер не запустился, остаётся блок со стандартной прокруткой.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете скрыть элементы слайдера (все слайды, кроме первого) до его полной загрузки. Таким образом, при начале загрузки страницы, пользователь увидет только лишь первый слайд, а после полной инициализации **slick-slider**, все остальные слайды станут активными.

```
/*устанавливаем неактивными все слайды в слайдере кроме первого*/
.slider .slide:not(:first-child) {
   display: none;
}

/*устанавливаем все слайды в слайдере активными после инициализации slick-slider*/
.slider.slick-initialized .slide:not(:first-child) {
   display: block;
}
```